# Mysql DATETIME to unix timestamp JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, unix-timestamp

Heya heres a (hopefully) easy one,

how can I convert this DATETIME value:

```
2014-01-16 12:00:00
```

to an unix timestamp via JavaScript or JQuery?

In PHP It is easy but in JavaScript it seems hard. I found out that Date.parse() or new Date() provide me that but this only helps with timestamps containing this other format with day of the week.

Is there a way to convert this 'numeric' variant aswell?

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to convert this string to a Javascript date format, you need to replace the space character between date and time with the character `T` in order to create a valid ISO8601 format. Then you can use `.getTime()` for the unix timestamp of this date.

```
var timestamp = new Date('2014-01-16 12:00:00'.replace(' ', 'T')).getTime();
```

Comment: this is the best solution after been looking like an hour, tks

Comment: This works, but if you don't give it a specified time (like 00:00:00), then it will print out a timestamp from the day before(which is inaccurate) Please see this https://jsfiddle.net/dkv8hzmo

Answer (score 3):

You could do this, but note `2014-01-16 12:00:00` is the local time of the machine.

```
var ts = new Date('2014-01-16 12:00:00').getTime() / 1000;
```

Update:

As @devnull69 said, Firefox only accepts the ISO format, you have to replace the space to `T`.

Comment: This is exactly what I found and did before my timestamp format (one example) is exactly: 2014-01-17 10:00:00 but whenever I try to parse it via new Date() or Date.parse() and do an alert, I get "Invalid Date" or "NaN" as result.

Comment: check my answer below, the string needs to be modified before passing it to `new Date()`

Comment: Firefox only accepts the ISO format ... other browser are more flexible in this regard

Answer (score 0):

`Date.prototype.getTime` returns a unix timestamp in milliseconds. If you want it in seconds, divide it by 1000.

```
function mysql_to_unix(date) {
    return Math.floor(new Date(date).getTime() / 1000);
}

mysql_to_unix("2014-01-16 12:00:00"); // returns 1389870000
```

Comment: This is exactly what I found and did before my timestamp format (one example) is exactly: 2014-01-17 10:00:00 but whenever I try to parse it via new Date() or Date.parse() and do an alert, I get "Invalid Date" or "NaN" as result.

Comment: @Up, it was an encoding problem. Devnull solved it for me, thanks for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>
        function test(date){
            n=date;
            var d=new Date(n).getTime() / 1000
            console.log(d);
        }
        </script>
        <body onLoad="test('2014-01-16 12:00:00')">
        </body>
```